# Unable to load html file in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a view controller that has a UIWebView. I want to load a html file in the UIWebView.
I have kept my html file under the Supporting files(Generated by Xcode)->Resources->html.
Also , I have created the html file and dragged and dropped in to the Html folder. 
My code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"contact" 
                              ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"Resources/html"] ;
     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFile    ];
     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [_webView loadRequest:request];
     _webView.delegate=(id)self;
}
```

What am I missing here . Looks a silly one but no luck..
Please help.

Comment: Refer this link
http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-iOS--Day-14%E2%80%93The-UIWebView

Comment: It's working randomly ...i have table cell and for index=0 it's working but not for other cell indexes..

Answer (score 0):

Replace your view did load method with this method. I checked with it. It's working for me. See that your html file should be placed as shown in image.(As per your need[image: My sample project image])

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        UIWebView *webView=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
        webView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
        NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"contact" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];
        NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        //Append javascript
        //NSString *script = @"<script>alert(\"This is an alert!!\");</script>";
        //htmlString = [htmlString stringByAppendingString:script];
        webView.delegate = self;
        [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
        [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

Comment: you can take help from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629965/locate-a-html-file-in-uiwebview