# Locate a html file in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a NotificationVC containing table view having 10 cells index 0 to 9. on click of each cell NotificationWebVC should open up that has a UIWebView that loads diff. html depending upon which cell is selected in NotificationVC. Right now my code works only for index=0 , but not for other indexes , seems bit weird.

```
NotificationWebVC
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:_resourceName ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil] ;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFile];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:request];
    _webView.delegate=(id)self;


}
```

Please suggest. _resourceName is a property having the name of html file.

Comment: maybe you can show the didSelectRowAtIndexPath where you call the NotificaitonVC

Comment: @joshua thats not possible because thats the parent VC and i want to load in the child VC having the webView.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:_resourceName ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil] ;

        [_webView loadHTMLString:htmlFile baseURL:nil];
        _webView.delegate=(id)self;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make an array containing your 10 urls. Then when a user tap on each cell, use the **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** delegate method.

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[resources objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil] ;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFile];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:request];
    _webView.delegate=(id)self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add line of code to NotificationWebVC.h

```
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *resopnseString;
```

then in .m class synthise it

```
@synthesize resopnseString;
```

after this go to didSelectMethod of tablevew datasouce in NotificationVC.m
there you add the following code

```
NotificationWebVC *notif=[[NotificationWebVC alloc]init];
notif.resopnseString=[resources objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//here it may present view or push view or what ever it be
```

After doing all this now you shift to NotificationWebVC.m
add the following code to in viewDidLoad method

```
 NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:resopnseString ofType:@"html"];
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile];
[webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

after doing all this pl z be  sure to add all 10 HTML file in your project
and try to check that you are getting correct html file on select in table from

be sure you are passing correct name of file in responsString

```
 [resources objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

or better put

```
 NSLog(@"%@",[resources objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
```

to it check it.

i think this code will help you

Comment: @kamalesh..just noticed when i pass the name of html file pathForResource:@"Filename" instead pathForResource:_resourceName ..it works fine.. any guess why it's causing problem..@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *resourceName;

Comment: better you synthesize it or use it with _resourceName

Comment: hey you are passing filename to nextview

Comment: can you post code where i can check it.wait i will make some correction and send you caomplete code to you

Answer (score 0):

```
// docfileName should be your file name call this method in tableview delegate didSelectrow

-(void)loadLocaldataonWebview :(NSString *)docfileName 
{
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:docfileName ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[documentsWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
}
```

then in viewDidload add the following code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
documentsWebView=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
documentsWebView.delegate=self;
documentsWebView.frame=CGRectMake(0, yAxis, kWidth, 616);
documentsWebView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:documentsWebView];

}
```